# Probability of different coloured counters being removed from a bag in a specific sequence

Tags: probability

A paper bag contains n counters of each of 4 different colours (i.e. 4
n counters in total). These are selected at random one by one from the bag until they have all been removed. What is the probability that they repeat the same four-counter cycle through the colours until the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it with colors $R,G,B,Y$.

If I understand you well then you are asking for the probability on arrangements like: $$RGBYRGBY\cdots$$ Correct me if I am wrong.

There are $4!$ orderings for the colors $R,G,B,Y$.

Looking at a fixed color there are $n!$ arrangements.

This gives $4!n!^4$ possibilities on a total of $(4n)!$ possibilities.

So the probability equals:$$\frac{4!n!^4}{(4n)!}$$